# Replacing exact usernames in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to replace occurences in a string into something else. Lets say I have the following sentence:

```
Hi @john.doe, i see @john has tagged you
```

I have 2 usernames in this sentence: `@john` and `@john.doe`. I want this to become this sentence:

```
Hi @john.doe(1), i see @john(2) has tagged you
```

I’m doing it like this:

```
Text = text.replace(username, ‘${username}(${userId})’);
```

The problem is, when I loop over all usernames in the string and do a replace for each username, because `@john` is a username but also a part of another username, it doesn’t work.

How can I replace exact words in a string in js?

Comment: Use a regexp with a negative lookahead that matches any characters that can be in a username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the usernames and replace them if they exist with the desired format:

```js
let str = 'Hi @john.doe, i see @john has tagged you, reply back to @john.';
const usernames = new Map([['john.doe', 1], ['john', 2]]);

[...usernames.entries()].forEach(([u, i]) => {
  const reg = new RegExp(`@${u}(?![a-z0-9_.-])|@${u}(?=\.$)`, 'g');
  if (str.match(reg)) {
    str = str.replace(reg, `${u}(${i})`);
  }
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: The numbers behind the usernames are their IDs, not indexes in an array. So when a username is 2 times in a string, it should have the same id behind it.

Comment: @SamLeurs in this case you can use a Map to append the proper id

Comment: I've tested your code and it works! Thank you very much! Have a nice day.

Comment: It breaks if you end your sentence with a period instead of an exclamation mark.

Comment: You could add `|@${u}(?=\.$)` to the existing RegExp to handle the edge case of your sentence ending in a period following a username.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to sort your usernames in descending order by their lengths, then try to replace/apply those in the given string? That’ll resolve your issue. Just make sure that while replacing values, if an id is already appended to a username, then skip those. Try this and let me know if this works for you.